# Endless scrollview with progress bar using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, infinite-scroll, android-scrollview, android-gridlayout

How to make Grid layout with endless scrolling and progress bar getting date using retrofit?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of `getViewType()` endless scrolling is straight forward

U can reference here

- [JOE'S GREAT ADAPTER HELL ESCAPE](http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/adapter-delegates)